# RefreshControl is not working when scroll down

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my App, I have added the RefreshControl in Class component. But when I try to scroll down to refresh it won't work. At the moment I have hardcoded the data but I'm looking forward to adding API data. I couldn't figure out the issue, appreciate any Help

##Code##

```
export default class ServiceTicket extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            refreshing : false,
        }
    }

    onRefresh = () =>{
        this.setState({refreshing :  true });
        setTimeout(() => {  this.setState({refreshing :  false }); }, 5000);       
        console.log("done!")
    };

render() {
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => ( <Item title={item.title} Serial={item.Serial}/> );
    const {onRefresh, refreshing} = this.state

    return(
        <>
        <View style={styles.item}>
        <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView scrollEnabled={false}         
        refreshControl={<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing}  onRefresh={onRefresh} /> }>
            <Card borderRadius={25} style={{paddingRight: 15}} >
                <Card.Content>

                <View style={styles.parent}>
                                <View style={styles.imgContainer}>
                                    <Image
                                        source={require('../assets/img/userAvt.png')}
                                        style={styles.image}
                                    />
                                    {/* <Text> {profile.user.photoUrl} </Text> */}
                                </View>
                                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Customer Name</Text>
                                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                                        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>
                                            #data.id </Text>
                                            {/* <Text> at {data.visitingAdd1}</Text> */}
                                    </View>
                                    <Text >data.visitingAdd1</Text>
                                    <Text >data.visitingAdd2</Text>
                                    <Text >data.visitingAdd3</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Contact Person</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Concern data.topic</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Warranty Status </Text>
                                    <View style={styles.devider} />
                                    <Text>data.createdAt</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>

                </Card.Content>

        </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this.onRefresh** keyword is missing

```
<RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing}  onRefresh={this.onRefresh} /> }>
```

You are trying to access **onRefresh** function from the **state** but it doesn't exist there

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you are closing the scrollview.
I guess it should be above the closing SafeAreaView.